# How to get the error-message back to client using try/catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm am trying to figure out how to get the error messages from /api/persons/index.js when for example the validation fails. I get the error in the chrome console but can't understand how to make it available in the client so that I can display some better error information to the user. I have been trying with try/catch in all files and also other combinations but am not able to get the error message back. What is the right way to do this?

`Form.js` file:

```
import personService from "../services/person";

...
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
...
const savedPerson = await personService.save(newPerson);
}
```

`/services/person.js` file:

```
const baseUrl = "/api/persons";
const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" };

const save = async (newPerson) => {
  try {
    const result = await fetch(baseUrl, {
      method:"POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(newPerson),
    });
    const savedPerson = await result.json();
    return savedPerson;
  } catch (error) {
    return error
  }
};
```

`/api/persons/index.js` file:

```
import dbConnect from "./../../../lib/dbConnect";
import Person from "../../../models/person";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;
  await dbConnect();
  const persons = await Person.find({});
  switch (method) {
    case "GET":
      res.status(200).json(persons);
      break;
    case "POST":
      const { body } = req;
      try {
        const newPerson = new Person(body);
        const savedPerson = await newPerson.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedPerson);
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json(error);
      }

      break;
    default:
      res.status(400).json({ itemnotfound: "No item found" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you are returning (not throwing) the error from `person.js` file, you cannot catch it from the `handler()`. Instead, you can always throw the caught error from `person.js` so that handler can deal with it later. or do it the better way, you can return something like `{status: 0, error: "error message",  data:null}` on failure and `{status: 1, error: null,  data:Person}` in case of success... of course, what you do is your own choise... just make sure that it is consistent across all APIs.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. That was a great solution